# How to fix Errors in IE

Tags: javascript

I am uisng IE 6 .

My page is working fine under Mozilla , but when i try to open the page from IE it shows an Error as

```
LINE : 553
Char :82
Error: Expected identifier , String or number 
code :0
```

please advice

Comment: Could you please give more information about the page you are loading?

Comment: may be you'll show us the code?

Comment: not related to the question per se, but I have worked with clients using IE6 still -- in particular the online world in places like Taiwan seems to be full of them, so there is probably a reason for using IE6.

Comment: @Mikaveli, In China, IE 6 is still the NO.1 in the market.

Comment: http://www.theie6countdown.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Best way to deal with:

1. Find the line and the "char", where the error is;
2. If the error is not at that line, look the previous line(for missing ; or wrong syntax);
3. If the error is not on the previous line, examine backwards. If single or double quote omitted, the error will appear several lines after.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much , how to Find the line and the "char", where the error is , because it shows line 553 and when i see as view page source i cant find that line .

Comment: @user663724: Load the page in a text editor that displays line numbers... or use a proper debugging tool.

Comment: Load the page in a text editor that displays line numbers , could you please tell me how to do this ??

Comment: Every text editor supports that. In most cases is in the lower right corner. http://img863.imageshack.us/i/editor.png/

Answer (score 2):

I would bet you have a trailing comma at the end of an array or object.

Also you are using a browser that is 11 years old. It is like using a model T in a formula one race. Yeah it works, but you are just slow and way behind on the technology front.